# How to position UIView properly using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, position

I read a lot of answers to questions that are similar to my question. But still could not figure this issue I am having.

I am adding UIView on top of another UIView.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
```

Here is how I add the another view on top of contentView.

```
 func showPopupView(){
    popupView.bounds.size.width = contentView.bounds.size.width
    popupView.bounds.size.height = self.view.frame.height - 99
    popupView.frame.origin.y = contentView.frame.origin.y + 50
    popupView.center.x = contentView.center.x
    view.addSubview(popupView)
}
```

I calculate 99 as 49 + 50. 49 is height of TabBar height and 50 is the height of a view on top.

However, popup view is not shown as intended on all simulator sizes. It is being displayed as intended on iPhone SE, but on iPhone 6, iPhone 6s or iPhone X there are gaps.

How should I position the popup view on superview (`self.view`)?

Comment: gap on top or bottom ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan on top and it varies based on device.

Comment: You only need to set the frame rectangle. You shouldn’t need to set bounds and center.

Comment: @Spads popup view height and width changes based on device its displayed in.

Comment: top view height is static or proportional to screen that is 50 ???

Comment: Use auto-layout constraints - most of the work will be done for you.

Comment: @Sh_Khan yes it has constraint of 50 height it is static.

Comment: what about contentView ???

Comment: @Sh_Khan it has constraints on all four sides to top(50 header), to bottom(49 TabBar), to sides.

Comment: tell me what is the contentView ?? it;s position ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan I have HeaderView on top. TabBar on the bottom. and ContentView is between to hold all the UI elements. It stretches between. I want popupView to cover on top of contentView. Which it does but does not cover all the contentView. There are gaps on tops between devices.

Comment: try this  popupView.frame.origin.y =  50  this makes only header above

Comment: @Sh_Khan it does not work. Same, works on one device not on others. I also tried adding additional 20 for safe area. Not solved.

Comment: @Spads you were right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to properly position my popupView on all device types via below code.

```
func showPopupView(){
    let statusBarHeight = self.view.safeAreaInsets.top
    showPopupView.frame.size.width = contentView.frame.size.width
    showPopupView.frame.size.height = contentView.frame.height
    showPopupView.frame.origin.y = contentView.frame.origin.y + statusBarHeight
    showPopupView.center.x = contentView.center.x
    view.addSubview(showPopupView)
}
```

With this code, `popupView` gets the height and width of the `contentView`. With `statusBarHeight` in mind, positions itself on top of it on the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong on a couple of levels.

1. You have a couple of "magic numbers" in your code
2. You are manipulating your view's frames. Don't do that. Auto-Layout is likely to trash your sizing and placement. Instead create auto-layout constraints (take a look at layout anchors. They're pretty easy to use.)

Comment: popupView is at SceneDeck, how I can use Auto-Layout there?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    popupView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 50),
    popupView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
    popupView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)
    ])
   if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    popupView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)])

 } else {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    popupView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor)])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd **highly** recommend to use `autolayout`, instead of hardcoding:

```
class SomeController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
    func showPopupView() {
        let popupView = UIView()   // or any other way how your `popupView` should be initialized
        view.addSubview(popupView) // Adding popup view before the setting anchors
        popupView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor)   // constant is 0 by default, could be any else
        popupView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor) // constant is 0 by default, could be any else
        popupView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 50) // same top position as `contentView`'s top plus 50 points
        popupView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, constant: -100) // same haight as `contentView`'s haight minus 100 points
    }
}
```

**Note**: I'm assuming that `contentView` is subview of a `view`. Also, `popupView` should be added to subviews before the using `anchors`.

Comment: popupView is at SceneDeck, how I can use Auto-Layout there?